# Custom tab bar doesn't show navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I'm currently working with multi-storyboard project, and I'm make an custom `UIView` inside an UIViewController (I named it "Tab Bar VC") and make it look like a tab bar with the tutorial from this link:
https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

Everything show up normally but the problem is when I press on tab bar items the navigation bar doesn't show and I can't push to another view controller without it. I have tried to embed my "Tab Bar VC" in navigation controller like this picture but it's doesn't work:
Note that in my case I don't wanna use `UITabBarViewController` or `Storyboard Reference`. Please help me.
Thank in advance.
[image]
Here is my code of Tab Bar VC:

```
#import "SHTabViewController.h"
#import "SHHomeViewController.h"
#import "SHTicketViewController.h"
#import "SHNotificationViewController.h"
#import "SHChatViewController.h"
#import "SHCallViewController.h"

@interface SHTabViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *viewcontrollers;
    NSInteger selectedIndex;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *tabButtons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SHHomeViewController *homeVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SHCallViewController *callVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SHChatViewController *chatVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SHTicketViewController *ticketVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SHNotificationViewController *notifVC;

@end

@implementation SHTabViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    selectedIndex = 0;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    selectedIndex = 0;
    UIStoryboard *homeStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIStoryboard *callStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CallPM" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIStoryboard *chatStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Chat" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIStoryboard *ticketStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Ticket" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIStoryboard *notifStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Notification" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self.homeVC = [homeStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeVC"];
    self.callVC = [callStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"callVC"];
    self.chatVC = [chatStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatVC"];
    self.ticketVC = [ticketStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ticketVC"];
    self.notifVC = [notifStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notificationVC"];
    viewcontrollers = [NSMutableArray new];
    [viewcontrollers addObject:self.homeVC];
    [viewcontrollers addObject:self.callVC];
    [viewcontrollers addObject:self.chatVC];
    [viewcontrollers addObject:self.ticketVC];
    [viewcontrollers addObject:self.notifVC];

    [self.tabButtons[selectedIndex] setSelected:YES];
    [self didPressTab:self.tabButtons[selectedIndex]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)didPressTab:(UIButton *)sender {
    selectedIndex = 0;
    sender.selected = YES;
    NSInteger previousIndex = selectedIndex;
    selectedIndex = sender.tag;
    [self.tabButtons[previousIndex] setSelected:NO];
    UIViewController *previousVC = viewcontrollers[previousIndex];
    [previousVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [previousVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    [previousVC removeFromParentViewController];

    UIViewController *vc = viewcontrollers[selectedIndex];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    [self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed 'Tab bar VC' with UINavigationViewController. Embed UINavigationViewController with each of a individual UIViewControllers you added in 'Tab bar VC'.

Comment: I have tried, but not work. And I'm not use TabBarController, I use an custom view and make it look like a tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should embed all individual view controllers with a navigation controller.

TabBarController > NavigationController > Viewcontroller

Comment: I have tried, but not work. And I'm not use TabBarController, I use an custom view and make it look like a tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
    For this you need to add a NavigationController for every Controllers like below


   -(void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        selectedIndex = 0;
        UIStoryboard *homeStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIStoryboard *callStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CallPM" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIStoryboard *chatStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Chat" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIStoryboard *ticketStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Ticket" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIStoryboard *notifStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Notification" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.homeVC = [homeStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeVC"];
        self.callVC = [callStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"callVC"];
        self.chatVC = [chatStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatVC"];
        self.ticketVC = [ticketStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ticketVC"];
        self.notifVC = [notifStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notificationVC"];

     UINavigationController *homeNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.homeVC];
     UINavigationController *callVCNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.callVC];
     UINavigationController *chatVCNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.chatVC];
     UINavigationController *ticketVCNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.ticketVC];
     UINavigationController *notifVCNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.notifVC];


        viewcontrollers = [NSMutableArray new];
        [viewcontrollers addObject: homeNavController];
        [viewcontrollers addObject: callVCNavController];
        [viewcontrollers addObject:ticketVCNavController];
        [viewcontrollers addObject:chatVCNavController];
        [viewcontrollers addObject: notifVCNavController];

        [self.tabButtons[selectedIndex] setSelected:YES];
        [self didPressTab:self.tabButtons[selectedIndex]];
```

Comment: I tried. It's crashed and return an error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`

Comment: Oh..My dear friend I got your problem you have taken custom UIView where you added few Buttons like Tabbar  and on that button action load controller as child. This the reason you are unable to show navigationbar

Comment: Do One thing Add this controller Parent Of all controller and within parent class write navigation logic for every controller..Parent controller UI display on all above basic controller look like Tabbar..

Comment: That was I mean. Sorry because the demo picture is look like a real tab bar. So you have confused about it. Can you help me about this problem? I'm missing navigation bar in every screen and I can push to other vc

Comment: My second comment is your problem solution... like below

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong approach. You are embedding tab bar controller in a navigation controller which logically doesn't make any sense.Instead you should embed various navigation controllers into one tab bar controller. Try doing something like this:[image]